# Pandas truncating display even after setting max_colwidth to -1

Tags: python, pandas

I am learning text mining and was working on twitter data by following code from [here](http://adilmoujahid.com/posts/2014/07/twitter-analytics/)

Although the code is for 2.xx I have converted it to 3.xx. I have only used the code till the graph to plot the top 5 countries after which I wanted to extract english only tweets from the data and write it to a text file, which I did as follows

```
eng_tweets = tweets.loc[tweets['lang'] == 'en', 'text']

with open('eng.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as engtweets:

    print(eng_tweets, file = engtweets)
```

While this does provide me with the english only tweets they are truncated (with ...) after about col 150 in notepad if they are quite a bit longer. I searched on stackexchange and found the solution, to set max_colwidth to -1, which I did as follows

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)  
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
pd.set_option('display.width', 200)
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
pd.set_option('display.float_format', '{:20,.2f}'.format)
```

Even then the text in the .txt file is truncated.
Any help would be appreciated.

This is for extracting twitter data using tweepy.

**EDIT**
Here are the links to the full [code](https://pastebin.com/NahwSPH9) and part of the [txt](https://pastebin.com/eLRZPG4d) file I am working with

**EDIT 2**
Sorry, forgot to mention here are some of the current lines of text from the file "eng.

> 719    Nah... I saw Gerald’s Game on @Netflix 
>   720    RT @AnnaApp91838450: The Obamas and Netflix Just Revealed the Shows and Films They’re Working On \nPatriots Time To S…

**EDIT 3**
I am a doofus. The commands are all working fine and thanks for the help but when it is an extended comment

```
 tweet['text']
```

Does not give the complete tweet. It has to be extracted from "extended_tweet" key.

Comment: try restarting the Notebook

Comment: @Andy_101 Done....Still no change

Comment: try using other values to see if you get any change, like 10000 insted of -1

Comment: Tried that as well....The only change is of alignment. When I use -1, everything is left aligned but with a large value like 2000, it gets right aligned

Comment: `pd.set_option('display....` only controls the display of the data, it doesn't change anything of the data itself.  Is the text still truncated in your eng.txt file after `eng_tweets.to_csv('eng.txt', index=False)`? If so then it comes already truncated from the preprocessing.

Comment: @Stef Will it not give me truncated entry as well because it just converts the txt to csv, where the txt itself has truncated data?

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to verify it in a second way. You're right that print and to_csv just print the data as is so therefore I said if you're data is truncated in the .txt file then it has nothing to do with display options but with the data itself that get truncated at some earlier moment.

Comment: I am away from my laptop currently but I remember trying to just print it without writing it to a txt for and still faced the same problem. And what I meant with txt to csv conversion is that, let's say that the txt file is being truncated by pre processing or because of display issues. I have no way of knowing which is the culprit as i am using the faulty file as input.

Comment: please provide what data you have and how you want it to be printed. Some example will be nice.

Comment: @Andy_101 Sure....Adding it to the main question

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i solved with this:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_column', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_seq_items', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 500)
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', True)
```

or you can just set everything as None:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_column', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_seq_items', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', True)
```